# Как программно прервать DragMove?

Tags: c#

Как программно прервать перетаскивание окна, вызванное методом `TheWindow.DragMove()`?

**UPD:**

Попробовал предложенный способ

```
CurrentWindow.QueryContinueDrag += new QueryContinueDragEventHandler((o,ee) => { Console.WriteLine("qwe"); ee.Action = DragAction.Cancel; });
CurrentWindow.DragMove();
```

Метод не срабатывает. В консоль ничего не выводится.

Answer (score 1):

Здесь суть в том, где именно ты применяешь драгмув. Например безсмысленно применять драгМув к Клику. Нужно применять к МаузДаун или PreviewMouseDown

Например так:

```
private void Window_MouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.ChangedButton == MouseButton.Left)
        this.DragMove();
}
```